# Integrating TIBCO Jasper Reports to web

Tags: jasper-reports

I am currently working on web application based on Angular JS,HTML5. I have a report section on the same where i am displaying the report data through API calls.

I feel that displaying reports through API call is not the best practice so i did some research and came across TIBCO Jasper reports and its looking fine till now.

What i have done till now is

1. Installed Jaspersoft Studio in my local machine.
2. Connected the same to my DB and generated JRXML file.
3. Uploaded the JRXML file to jasper server and generated reports from DB.

What i need to do is

1. I see i can generate reports in various formats from jasper server like pdf, excel etc.. How do i integrate this to my web page?

Please assist me on this and share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ""Make a button and then call the page that displays the pdf or load it through a blob in a iframe", this question seems very broad... try to get started with some examples on the web and then come back if you get stuck....

Comment: How does the data get updated when it change in DB if i display a pdf

Comment: You re-create the pdf. you can't update a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the community or professional version? If you are using the professional version, you can use their Visualize.js library to access your reports from a web application. We have had success integrating Jasper reports into our Angular app, though we've found it to be pretty buggy and it has required several workarounds on our part.

We started by creating an Angular service that handles all the communication with Visualize/Jasper. Once you get all the service plumbing done, it's just a matter of creating an empty DIV tag with an ID and passing that ID to the Visualize function that generates the report. Visualize will handle the REST request to the Jasper server and automatically inject the JS and HTML returned into your empty DIV.

You can find more info on Visualize (including API docs) here:

[community.jaspersoft.com/project/visualizejs](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/visualizejs)

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate JasperServer into your web app using iFrames with their HTTP API. This would allow you to reuse the UI that is part of JasperServer. It is possible to customize the look and feel of this UI using themes. More info here:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-using-http-api